# Which core module provides the default send email action for use in rules?

Tags: views

There is a core module (might be related to core actions) that allows your to send an email via VBO. What is the name or where is that function located in core?

For e.g. When I am modifying the system mail settings, what "module" in core provides this functionality? (See screenshot)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a part of the system.module; precisely the [system_send_email_action()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_send_email_action/7) function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "module", at least not one that can be turned on and off like other modules. Emails are normally handled by drupal_mail() and a bunch of other functions found in the `system.mail.inc` file under /modules/system and `mail.inc` found in /includes .  These work together to create the framework, using templates that you can set up in order for other modules (like VBO) to actually send emails.

[drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7):

> Sending an e-mail works with defining an e-mail template (subject,
>   text and possibly e-mail headers) and the replacement values to use in
>   the appropriate places in the template. Processed e-mail templates are
>   requested from hook_mail() from the module sending the e-mail. Any
>   module can modify the composed e-mail message array using
>   hook_mail_alter(). Finally drupal_mail_system()->mail() sends the
>   e-mail, which can be reused if the exact same composed e-mail is to be
>   sent to multiple recipients.

Comment: What batch of code provides the re-usable action to send mail in rules then?

Comment: I have no idea, and no reason to know. you would have to look through the Rules code for that

Comment: It's not provided by rules, it's provided by core for rules. I just need to know which core module has this functionality built in. I realize the core module that provides this functionality provides for more than this feature but one of the modules still provides it.

Comment: I don't believe there is a 'module' - it is part of the core API using drupal_mail() and related functions as indicated in the answer. I don't know why you keep thinking there's a module - most of core is done through the API, not through actual modules

Comment: I found it, it is in the system.module https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_send_email_action/7

Answer (score 1):

VBO gets those actions from rules.

The functions are into rules module:

PATH_TO_YOUR_MODULES/rules/modules/system.rules.inc